# CSS background text filling the box

Tags: html, css, background, fill

I'm trying to make a copy of a website as my first CSS/HTML exercise. 
I can't figure out how to make the menu list so it has its background filling the box (extending until the right border).

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGZZT.png) of what I have now (right side of the picture, red lines show where the background should go) and what I want to get (left side).

My [code](https://jsfiddle.net/e5bot29o/1/).

I've tried so far to achieve it e.g. with 'width' and 'display' parameters, but e.g. `display: block;` remove the lines between text. I'm out of ideas.

Comment: id="menu"     a id just use once in a html. You can change to class="menu".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 2px;
```

to the #menu

Comment: Thank, `margin-bottom` seems to be key for my problem.

Comment: @oboer No. The problem is that spans are inline elements. Also pay attention to the ID and class (as I mentioned in my answer).

Answer (score 1):

`spans` are inline elements so they cannot have `width` or `height`. You should put a `background-color` to your `li` elements instead of your `spans`.

```
.menu{
   background-color: grey; //Change it to your custom colour.
}
```

Also, **you cannot have more than one element with the same `ID`**. You have to put them as a class.

[Updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e5bot29o/3/).

Comment: Thanks for tips about `id` and `spans`, I'll bear them in my mind. Voted up, but my vote will be displayed when I reach 15 rep.

Comment: @oboer You have to be aware of how each element is displayed on the webpage. For example, when you display a `span` like a `block` it acts like a `block` so it will have height/width. As a span is inline element by default, it is why it is not covering the full width of your li elements. And also be careful with ID's and class. It is very important to use ID only in **unique** elements. Cheers! :)